# BeagleBone AI OpenCL

Tags: linux, darknet, yolov4

I have a project to run yolov4 on BeagleBone AI. To run this CNN I needed to install Darknet using following guide: https://iblog.isowa.io/2020/04/29/darknet-in-opencl-on-beagleboard-ai/ . I suggest that installation held good.
The key is that with this guide Darknet supports OpenCL what can increase detection speed on embedded systems.
Then I've loaded testing photos and videos, config file and weights for yolov4 and use CCL:
''' `cd ~/sowson cd darknet ./darknet detector demo ./darknet/data ./cfg/yolov4-obj.cfg ./weights/yolov4.weights photo1.jpg`
'''

And I have the following error:

1. TIOCL WARNING: Opening Linux shared memory: No such file or Directory.
2. TIOCL FATAL: The TI Multicore Tools daemon (/usr/bin/ti-mctd) is not running. To start daemon, rm /dev/shm/HeapManager (if exists); ti-mctd. Re-run application. Refer User Guide for details.
   Aborted.

I do not understand how to fix it, did not find any information in the Internet actually.

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that product but judging from the error messages you need to provide a SysV shared memory region (fancy term for a structured RAMDISK).  On my server the entry in /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec,seclabel 0 0
```

During system boot this gets mounted automatically but after adding a similar line to /etc/fstab you can activate it without a reboot like this:

```
# mount /dev/shm
```

and then try your test again.  If it works, reboot and test again just to make sure the solution is permanent.

Comment: Do you meand that I should write in command line #mount /dev/shm ? Or should I write tmpfs /dev/shm and then tmpfs rw, nodev, nosuid, noexec, seclabel 0 0 ?

Comment: I found file /etc/fstab and there're several strings there :
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
#Auto generated by RootStock-NG: setup_sdcard.sh
#
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /  ext4  noatime, errors=remount-ro  0  1
debugfs  /sys/kernel/debug  debugfs
mode=755, uid=root, gid=gpio, defaults  0  0

Should I just add string that you wrote (tmpfs   /dev/shm        tmpfs   rw,nodev,nosuid,noexec,seclabel 0 0) below everything that is written in fstab file?